# Не работает свойство , значение в сss

Tags: css, html5

[image: 1]
Задал свойство и значение в CSS файле все сделал как в курсе , а оно не применилось . Что не так?
Спасибо

Comment: Я ничего не вижу....картинка мелкая

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

**Скорее всего у вас не работает по причинам:**

1.Неправильное применение тега link.

2.Неправильный путь в теге link.

3.Наличие кода с ошибками (У вас, судя по всему, всё правильно, но я не доверяю русским буквам в main.css)

**Возможное решение:**

Попробуйте заменить свой link на: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">`

И, на время теста работы сайта, уберите русские буквы из main/css.

Comment: Большое  спасибо , помогло убирание русских слов !

Comment: Отметьте ответ правильным, пожалуйста! Это делается нажатием на галочку (она лежит слева от моего текста "**Возможное решение:**"). Просто хочется не только ответить, но и баллов заработать...